# I'm having trouble understanding how to perform a very basic chi squared test

Tags: chi-squared-test, binary-data, survey

I conducted a survey: I asked 50 participants a question about a device they were using "is this device helpful".
30 said "Yes", 20 said "No".

How do I proceed with input into a contingency table or input to online Chi squared calculator (expected and observed results)?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What do you want to test?

Comment: Thanks. Truly not too sure, little unfamiliar with stats, maybe you could give some advice?
I actually asked total of 5 different questions about the device, all are yes or no answers. What might be the best way to analyze this?

Comment: Do you want to know if the 30/20 ratio is statistically different from 25/25? Different from 45/5? Different from 10/40?

Comment: Sure 25/25 please

Comment: Please edit that into your original question. (Not everyone reads comments.)

Comment: What if my 'observed' results were 30 saying "yes" and 20 saying "no" as I mentioned above, but I wanted to calculate what the 'expected' results would be, in order to then proceed with my chi squared analysis. how might I do this?

Comment: Expected under what circumstances? If you think the proportion of “yes” responses is half, then you expect 25/25. If you think the proportion of “yes” responses is eighty percent, then you expect 40/10. It might be common to test if the ratio is half,  and that might be exactly what you want to do, but you aren’t obligated to do or want to do such a test.

Comment: Further to Dave's points -- I see no reason *a priori* to think that a proportion of "50% yes" is a reasonable null for a question like "Is this helpful?". Most devices are very carefully designed with the aim of being suitable for some purpose. Under what circumstances would *half* be a default (or interesting) thought on that question? (On a question like "which device do you prefer, A or B" I can see something like "no tendency to prefer A to B" as a plausible null to wish to test -- though an equivalence test might make more sense. That's a very different situation to "was this helpful?").

Comment: This case sounds to me much more like a question for which an estimate (both point and interval estimates make sense) might be useful to know but I don't see why comparison with 50/50 yes/no would be much practical use. What good is knowing *half* of people didn't find it helpful?

Comment: The main point remains @Dave's first comment, as expanded by Glen_b You need a hypothesis to test. An example of a more plausible null would be comparing males and females on whether they said Yes or No in the same proportions.

Comment: I don't see how a chi-square test would be helpful. What might be helpful is to compute the confidence interval of the proportion. 30/5 60% said yes. Assuming these are representative of a larger population, the 95% confidence interval extends from 46% to 72%.  Using this online calculator: https://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/confInterval1/